# Parking 2 wheelers on side stand

Tags: motorcycle, parking

I want to know if parking your 2 wheeler on side stand after a long ride would cause any harm to the engine parts in the sense that the oil from the oil pan would be moved to the other part due to gravity which could leave some parts of the engine  which is still very hot without oil and could cause oxidation of those parts.Is this true?

Comment: When you use the side stand what is the angle from vertical? and what is the size of the oil pan? which will give you the change in depth.

Comment: Its roughly abot 30 degrees from vertical and oil pan in my bike could hold 700 ml of oil

Comment: If it were truly a problem it would also occur while leaning into a turn. The real disadvantage of side stands is the chance of it sinking into the ground and the bike falling over.

Comment: So, size as in area? Length * width...

Comment: If side stands caused a problem like you described, they wouldn't have them. I have been riding for most of my life and have never come across any internal engine damage because of the bike leaning on the side stand while the engine is still warm/hot. Oil does not instantly wash away as soon as the engine stops or the bike is leaned. You would be surprised how much oil remains on parts while hot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only difference in oil when the bike is on it's sidestand compared to being level (whether it's running or not) is where the extra oil in the pan is located. Straight up and down and it will be even across the entire pan. On it's sidestand, it will pool to the side the sidestand is located on (usually the left).

The change in location of oil in the pan doesn't have an affect on anything. As long as your oil is filled to the proper level, it will still get picked up by the oil pump and circulated through the system. The internal components of the engine which you should really be concerned about getting oil aren't affected by the lean of the bike.